# Top-left pixel outside 100% width of the browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to load my webpage so that top-left pixel isn't the first one but rather somewhere else?

This is my current webpage layout and I'd like my webpage to be loaded so that top-left pixel is right where red arrow lands

[image]

Comment: You might want to reconsider your user name.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your username. Nobody would complain if it was "Bruce Wayne". Ignore him.

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? You can position things with negative values such as `top: -1000px` if that's what you need, but why do you need to do that? I ask because maybe we have some better suggestions to help you solve your actual problem.

Comment: just code it with your holy hand... but what @chev said.  use css padding/margin to change position.  if your position is relative, everything else will follow your first el's position.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/53u2s8xe/

this is basically my webpage. See how it's loaded with blank white page and when you scroll to the right you get to see basic layout. I've done it like this so that in About section when i click the right link (in #about section) it will scroll right to div #right and when i click the left link it will scroll left to div #left. I aleardy acomplished that transition with a jquery function i found on the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your request: it sounds like your goal is to have a single-column page and then exclusively in the about section with the right/left blocks you'd like to be able to scroll left/right.

If that's correct, I would restructure your page to have just the middle column, and then use css positioning on your #about section like this:

```
#about {position: relative;}
#left {position:absolute; left:-100%; width:100%; min-height:100%;}
#right {position:absolute; left:100%; width:100%; min-height:100%;}
```

You might need to do something with your body overflow, too:

```
body {overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Then to actually create the functionality you want, you could use javascript/jQuery to animate the sections left/right when you click on the anchors in the #about section.

Or you could use this js plugin, which works extremely well and is designed for just this type of layout: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: I'll giv that a try because that is exactly what I want. Let you know

Comment: With this plugin i am only able to make the left div as my starting one and scroll to the right only, if I'm not mistaken. I would really like to be able to click on my left anchor and then my #left transitions from left to right to fit the screen, not from the right to left. I haven't been able to do this with this  plugin though

Comment: Two options I can think of depending on how you want to approach it: 1) Use javascript to immediately 'click' the link to shift the section right when the page loads; or 2) try building it without the plugin and then shift the whole about section when you click the links (rather than moving the individual sub-sections).

Comment: Ok great, this did the job. Thank you once again

Comment: @JesusChrist you are mistaken. From the [fullPage.js documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#required-html-structure) "If you want to define a different starting point rather than the first section or the first slide of a section, just add the class active to the section and slide you want to load first."

Answer (score 0):

For whole container or body tag apply this css

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
```